# git reset --soft HEAD~ modifies staged snapshot?

Tags: git

From whatever I have read about **git reset --soft**, I learned that it doesn't modified staging area or the index. But in the below example you can see clearly that the staging area/index is modified as a result of **git reset --soft**. Why?

```
mkdir test;cd test;git init;
touch a;
echo 1 >>a;git add a;git commit -m"1" a;
echo 2 >>a;git commit -m"2" a;

git diff --cached; <NO OUTPUT>
git reset --soft HEAD~;
git diff --cached;<See the below output>

--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 1
+2
```

Comment: By the way, supplying paths to the `git commit` command is very special-purpose usage, and it's redundant in your first use of it here.

Answer (score 4):

The claim that `git reset --soft` leaves the index/staging-area unmodified is correct.

Note that `git diff` always compares two things.  Which two things does it compare?  The answer is a bit complicated for the fully general form of `git diff`, but you are using `git diff --cached`, and it compares the two things noted in [the `git diff` documentation`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

> `git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path> ...]`
>
> This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the named *`<commit>`*. Typically you would want comparison with the latest commit, so if you do not give *`<commit>`*, it defaults to `HEAD`. [snip]

Thus, the two things being compared are `HEAD` and the index.

#### Aside: the documentation is misleading

The above implies that the index stores *changes*, which is not true!  The index / staging area is simply *what would be in the next commit* if you made that commit right now.  Hence, after making a commit, the index and the current commit are identical—at least, they represent the same work-tree (the index omits significant parts of a commit, namely author and committer name+email+date, parent pointers, and commit message—or to put it a little more briefly, the index has *only* a work tree, and it's in an unusual form, more suited for being an index/cache than for being a commit).

#### Back to `git reset` and `git diff --cached`

`git reset --soft` modifies `HEAD`.  It does not modify the index.  You first compare `HEAD` against the index and see no output.  Then you change `HEAD`.  Now you compare the changed `HEAD` against the index, and see output.

What changed to cause the changed output?  Well, `HEAD` changed.

You can see the same thing by omitting the `git reset --soft` step and providing a specific commit:

```
git diff --cached HEAD~
```

This will compare commit `HEAD~` against the index, and show you the same output.

Comment: Index is the place which keeps the changes to be committed. I had nothing to be committed before reset. I added nothing to be committed after reset. Then how were the changes added to index?

Comment: The index does not store changes.  It stores *the next commit you can make*.  When the comparison between `HEAD` and "the next commit" is empty, there is nothing new to commit.  Changing `HEAD` changes the difference between `HEAD` and "the next commit" but does not change "the next commit" itself.  I'll edit this post to point out the flaw in the `git diff` documentation, which implies the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

A commit is of particular content.  The index indexes particular content.  `git diff --cached` compares indexed content against the named commit. When you reset `HEAD`, you changed the commit `git diff --cached` compares against.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation on git index is a bit misleading. The matter of fact is that *git index* is very much like commit, but without things like commit timestamp or email of person who made the commit. Git index contains certain state of your files. When you do `git checkout master` or make new commit git index contains references to the same files/blobs that are in the commit you just checked out or made. If you try to do `git commit` now nothing will happen because git will see that git index references the same files as last commit and therefore there is nothing to commit. When `index` differs from commit `HEAD` points to at the moment then new commit can happen recording whatever is in the index in that new commit. After the second commit your repository looks like this

```
      index
      |
#1 -> #2
      ^
      master
      ^
      HEAD
```

When you do `git reset --soft HEAD~` then your repo looks like this

```
      index
      |
#1 -> #2
^     ^
|     master
|
HEAD
```

Note that your local file also appears as in commit `#2` and therefore `git diff` should show you nothing. But `index` is now different from commit that `HEAD` points to. Hence `git diff --cached` shows you effective difference between commit `#1` and `#2`.